# Can't put Content-Type header in Interceptor

Tags: angularjs, http

I have many requests in the same structure as this one:

```
angular.module( 'factories' )
  .factory( 'encodedFormInterceptor', function( $window, $q, $http ) {
    return {
      request: function( config ) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        config.headers.Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

        return config || $q.when( config );
      },
      response: function( response ) {
        if ( response.status === 401 ) {

        }
        return response || $q.when( response );
      }
    };
  } );
```

But when I try to set the Content-Type header in a separate interceptor, like this:

```
angular.module( 'factories' )
  .factory( 'encodedFormInterceptor', function( $window, $q, $http ) {
    return {
      request: function( config ) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        config.headers.Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

        return config || $q.when( config );
      },
      response: function( response ) {
        if ( response.status === 401 ) {

        }
        return response || $q.when( response );
      }
    };
  } );
```

I get this error:

> ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
>
> config.headers.Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

I'm already using another interceptor for authorization, which works fine:

```
angular.module( 'factories' )
  .factory( 'AuthInterceptor', function( $window, $q ) {
    return {
      request: function( config ) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        if ( $window.localStorage.getItem( 'eva-token' ) ) {
          config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.localStorage.getItem( 'eva-token' );
        }
        return config || $q.when( config );
      },
      response: function( response ) {
        if ( response.status === 401 ) {

        }
        return response || $q.when( response );
      }
    };
  } );
```

So how can I put other header types in interceptors? I checked the AngularJS documentation but did not found an answer there.

Comment: What about the hyphen ? "config.headers.Content-Type" looks like wrong syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `-` in variable names.
Try:

```
config.headers["Content-Type"] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```